# Select entries by list of ids from subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In `PostgreSQL` database I make such SQL request:

**SQL**:

```
SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG (QUESTION_ID) AS QUESTIONS 
FROM 
    factors_questions_relationship 
WHERE 
    FACTOR_ID IN (SELECT ARRAY_AGG (FACTOR_ID) AS FACTORS 
                  FROM surveys_factors_relationship 
                  WHERE SURVEY_ID = '9bef1274-f1ee-4879-a60e-16e94e88df38');
```

**ERROR**:

> This SQL request raise error:
>   SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
>   No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Second subquery return list of ids: `{2,10,12,44,52}`. I want to use that list of ids in main query. How to make it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG (QUESTION_ID) AS QUESTIONS FROM factors_questions_relationship 
where FACTOR_ID IN 
(
   SELECT FACTOR_ID AS FACTORS FROM surveys_factors_relationship 
   WHERE SURVEY_ID = '9bef1274-f1ee-4879-a60e-16e94e88df38'
)
```

Comment: Hello! I tested your code right now. Unfortunately it raise error: `SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I don't know why but your code return empty result. In fact if I make such sql request `SELECT ARRAY_AGG (QUESTION_ID) AS QUESTIONS FROM factors_questions_relationship WHERE FACTOR_ID IN (2,10,12,44,52)` I have result like `{7,8,9,10,11,12,39,40,41,42,43,47,48}` which is correct. What do you think about that?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek, I've edited the answer - you can check now